# Overlapping Drawing

Tags: android, graphics, draw

I have bottom layer that has his draw method overridden.
Bottom Layer subclasses Constraint layout

```
override fun draw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.draw(canvas)
        val timePoints = getTimeRepresentation()
        var x: Float
        var y: Float

        // Draw Bottom Buffer
        //y = height - bottomBufferHeight
        canvas!!.drawRect(0f, height - bottomBufferHeight, width.toFloat() + converter.convertDpToPixel(2f), height.toFloat(), bufferPaint)
        // Draw Top Buffer
        y = topBufferHeight
        canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), y, bufferPaint)
        val heightOfHour = actualHeightOfHour()
        val textHeightOffset = textPaint.textSize /3

        // Draw Hours & Lines
        x = padding
        y += heightOfHour
        for (i in 0..23) {
            // Draw TimeText
            canvas.drawText(timePoints[i], x, y + textHeightOffset, textPaint)
            // Draw Line
            x += timeWidth + padding
            canvas.drawLine(x, y, width - padding, y, linePaint)
            // Set X, Y for next run
            x = padding
            y += heightOfHour

        }
    }
```

With initializer:

```
        linePaint = Paint()
        linePaint.color = resources.getColor(R.color.chronoView_line)
        linePaint.strokeWidth = converter.convertDpToPixel(1f)
        linePaint.isAntiAlias = true

        textPaint = Paint()
        textPaint.color = resources.getColor(R.color.inactive_on)
        textPaint.textSize = converter.convertDpToPixel(14f)
        textPaint.isAntiAlias = true

        bufferPaint = Paint()
        bufferPaint.color = resources.getColor(R.color.buffer_pale)
        bufferPaint.isAntiAlias = true
```

Then I add atop that view a few other ones but the line (linePaint) draws atop of those views as in bellow

Link: https://ibb.co/fvdyjDC
Alternate link: https://i.ibb.co/ySFZH48/Screen-Shot-2019-09-15-at-9-30-57-PM.png

The blue line is a separate view that is a child of this subclassed ConstraintLayout, and same goes to these New Task views that between them have line drawn over them...

I don't understand what is causing this, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but if you're trying to draw behind the child `View`s, you should instead override `onDraw()`, and do your drawing before the `super` call. Btw, please upload images here directly, by clicking [the image button above the edit box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRAP7.png). They will only be links in your post, but you can still upload them here.

Comment: Yeah, thats what it was. I mistakenly overridden the wrong method and wasn't even aware of it. Thanks Mike for pointing that out. And I tried with images, but it didn't work since I don't have enough rep points to post directly so I had to do the links, sorry about that.